# Can someone help me open this .file file?

Tags: file-extension

I found an old file of mine and I'm wondering if someone could identify its extension and help me open it. Every time I open it it opens Notepad with

```
`½18f%y_W}ÿuìGŽu–7Sƒ²+kÝqéÚ‘…ÓÎ,™ÂŠþ5WDuùxq­*ŽEØÑôoh0”¶™AÇ÷¸õÚã%¾â¸+Ü9ŠõSçÖf&:=µÄ6ý¥oß„ž
ÚO¹—§ÖÐ`™«¤_òÓµ
P‘ šâCç¶¢À—eìW"ŸÐEÎeÐ–K¹Ã(Ö†’,€0™-æ
}…sKFàš’}-D¬ømÛpõVR¶|ø;Hôí_ý¦ªeÀÆÒðæšÉÜRwž%—é÷  äšvz¹Á6ÂHr}gkôYpÞÕ”¹¦V1G³›XŽa_êè—T÷L{³ÿ¨²P4«Ïaøl(ôEiöVÆoNÓìCU*ËHÜ!µ—Y·¨Ktœ)~íMò2Ë-×íü)aµ=²( ±ÊbÍT‰Ê·ùðÕ«m¥&_QD*ŸC"Ex©OxŠs…)À<®‡úyüµãTë)‰'t|',lÿ€&I˜?‚êWp:KÍ2 
‚ý‡S<-»¼í.F=jryB7ðëÒ+žÅã‘ã$koôÈ½þîØýTÎú9vtpoè|®CRâ¼\¯žÊ½QçÓ ëÛÒú¾5ÑaIô;&–YW•awþ)žFo²s²`ã OQ£‘Jãý}ê/ÜÓ¿‰ž×Á…gI·ÉÅÉç¬Š‰jX+i#¡ÎËÏµ=z‚’Ö¦æ~¨¨b¢<-ãkÏÒÑ•B‚D–gVúÍ©Õ—4,ÉíwùÑ‰5D.›ž1ZêÈ¦© Û”mµü]ã àÁÙ'o?•×Œ3€Éx§‘»¹FSÝÊI0éÇ’B"ÚÆƒn[÷±,ëåŒj£;>&DQÉcåWè†\!½Ü8Ç¸ñ}·eWVHŽâq»Øz¡*¶Vx)]Êf´÷ªã§õò÷yÀ}Ïe 7gMç§†hÏÜ:Û‡ûÚUFÃ‚÷]ÁclÛVƒ„´$¡«¹lN5†.kŠÜü+§íâ­p=[¬åï›¿CfA–ÅÀõbödV›˜Þ¡\xŠ¸kœ²ÇædKÕý%*ƒa¾»   [kzé¼îÿDhMn¾ áOb·—u5paÝ.Ã-Bô@œ ž3–ÂÉ±}¨ê+>²>ÚÉÓ„h6·_ïõ"¶{W÷a7U+]ò¸2Aþ"@jvrÒö~ØMžË\!£e¤×,Ò Q¿t} ÏÈÍâà'‘Ò4ÜÑ‹ýå‚f±D^¿é†€âÜ€Ù7°¦Ó‡ÜÚ|¦ë€HñæÉJ»G]ªw‘ñ{w¨Ìf5®¹$uOì‰ž÷:óçÿm"Æ‚÷*Y´â=ë&(XF^+nŽ±ËU«¯‘×0È•
%,™DVžÒË!ËéA_ŸÚõ•¶•ï|fo£¯îu‹ž0±Ôˆ³V(–ÏéÝ4ð­:·ñ©Z?„5ÍÈw›1="˜3D¿£lO²V]X0x½[öóÕ°UOvûUÁ%C+[‹wb)Ë€ó|0°½ôGø.k·¯/J–O¥Ú?Ùšã!EP­ÞÙö]?PK¹b"ß>ƒßn«%6E$†oÊÛø›‰S0ÌÖ€Æ‚¦?ï"ÖB9[G,rhM÷&'Òºï&æBzÉ©§é¶ö‚-øÂQ%Œx(ÏL-{R'ÛZM@.Ü ²úYÞ€ßRÞõ©HçØ—;·æwAßš¢tšrb*ÑMÖû…ÇZÏ@õ¦&dòþ/ØK†õÿÅºàGXÄÔ^N .{_Ñ´Y‰ï Pdp
S¬âœlZ½¤ÌŽ#ÿ¾‰›ÀQ¯´‚f"mR´a¿º SÙ,tÓW£'j>Âyf–Ät*†g@h£m‹&ÂýùÙDŠbÇVb©yoTùíû¨ÔnþàS˜¾#º±÷,4È,1š¿ëÝåô-{í§
\ÏOütìDÎFØ<¦TRªg°Ã_GJ?Oë€«Ïs¤¤iI°èpCxøÌnã¯4:Xƒp«C%á˜6ò+(âÚŒ¡~ñá(½®£EÔÌ·"«)ˆnx–Ñº1-Çz¥Uïx…ežh/ÿIÍ‹ßºO£œ7óÚ¢dKªqù¡kZ~ _Ñ»ËS@ÞOË@Å®¢cì4dö»ç7Ö¨äš´V²»¾ñŽÄP©IÐ<[údbÎ£ô­õ´Šå‚ð5œ%å˜ÑŽ'J#]øà€úö¡ú—º Ï£j1 ‡•Ì¨|þÔ&«}{žšÞ›NÇ\Õõ âûûeÑÉ4<˜'ÜÝžVn:°*«Ó#ëAD]ìñODø^,áæ«Ž)‚‚G”PS7Dû‰˜%ö¾Èn¡çˆ¹ý&X$º¼Xy…²F%Ë{iÃ³ÒÝeãÙ½iÖÁ!«°Õ”jV%Î½¿æÃêHˆrWÕ¾§ºmªwß1eìbPa¶gY8ª™L )pø-i&Z›Pp†#·U¬Ð´é(¬0èy+¨ìz¬"<ô¶°ãuô‹Üõ?ÎF!r]•Ø|ª!·ïúHfä
ÄŒ6xPÔõþâ0‘$ ö;‚AÁDÃ ÚZåÄF2­ý3ÿÍØÀõÇA’ªÄš[¤ÄSÖº¸ ü½j[ÎP`tå> ÊfS2½l  å[ka¬ž2 ¼¹ÙË¯ëz­ª| ¼ÎÏ/[OaÂÍ³Øjg$üúªb¤x1øg¯Ö¬N›VõïÅA°‚ªäù×  õ,áorÝ*câ(B¾Õ½)NZÊp\(½,Œ˜¥êÖ\
§þYtA…yç96dJËWè¢Å7‡1¨‘½&»áJ'³|oÔ®µKò ªäms‚(ùfšÖs{ÈÒ„Û‘ÿ„Ò‘¥"Gƒ1êXNüñê‚øI¦³Cv0täÇ…°3„þRÀ¦'Ÿš/›ãÓàHcà8êKÂ˜½#{xËbD3žÑÿnÝ"@®™’“ŸÒò[</«¸6    ,«Äµ¨8kÊZ_€°"÷˜k?8vlÞ¨iÈï=ÍÝ{aÉÆ‰˜‚ž2gîú¼ÞéB… D¬¢þ‹ö#zÚ…×·›
5–©'Þ@âª$Ü™‰ùÛoÉTNÿ”"Ó[´W$—Ãž“(‰z·c}4 îŒ¨Vóñ‘"ƒ±ON)?mD™zB[¸
Š}m~öbMÞ< dC~®ÕŠð&ˆT[ŒW]Œ¿ø–±
ŽÑ»Z›<ñ-••«ÈåÝý<dõ*$[Å]7çê«Ihñ¬ªLà1xÂô¼
úÒ¸Š˜aUúZ”óËgÕ,IµÓÇAé6bÇúg
fa¶ª¦ø
>Ä6:›ÑµpªÌê`¨#ëº«[ú8ñð"žU;^‰
```

Comment: Can you share the file name?

Comment: You need a hex editor.  There are many free ones.  It is difficult to interpret non-printing chars when dumped into notepad.  Even then, this might be difficult.  Is there any purpose to opening this old file?

Comment: Do you have any hint about where this file might come from? Where did you find it and what leads you to think there is anything useful in it? Have you run it through any (online of offline) file type analyzer software?

Comment: The fact that you pasted it as "text"-data in the question may have distorted it beyond recognition; becaus of this linux `file` reports it as "UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines". So; the conclusion is; we cannot answer your question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have run it through a hex editor, I found it in my google drive and my late father shared it with me, i have a hex editor but haven't come to any conclusions.

Comment: @StarCat My late father shared the file with me and other than running it through a hex editor no, I haven't run it through a file analyzer software, I'll do that now.

Comment: I know this might be personal data.. so possibly sensitive.  If you post it, it is possible that it can be deciphered by one of us.  If you didn't start with a hex editor.. because that didn't occur to you, then you probably are not going to be successful.  If you do dump it into a hex editor and need to keep it private, you might start the first 128bytes or so and the last 16 or so.  This sounds like a noble cause.  I will do what I can but not hopeful that we will figure this out.